# How to check for words in a string even if the order is different - PYTHON

Tags: python, string, dictionary, set, anagram

I am trying to find make as many words with e.g. 'workbook'
So the results should be like: work, workbook, book, bookwork, bow, row etc.

This is one method I tried, but this won't find words that are spelled in different order. (e.g. it won't append 'bow' even though you could rearrange letters within 'workbook' to write 'bow')

```
f = open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r')

test = "workbook"
anagramlist = [] 

for word in f:
    if word[:-1] in test and len(word[:-1]) > 2: 
        anagramlist.append(word[:-1]) 
        # this wont append 'bookwork', 'row' etc 

print anagramlist #outputs ['boo', 'book', 'work', 'workbook']
```

Another method I tried approaching this problem is by using sets.. But this doesn't work entirely either because it appends words that for e.g have more than 1 'w's like 'wow' or 'wowwow', even though I want it to only use the number of letters and letters in 'workbook'

```
f = open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r')
test = "workbook"
anagramlist = []

for word in f:
    if len(word) > 2 and set(word[:-1]) == set(test) & set(word[:-1]): 
        anagramlist.append(word[:-1])

print anagramlist
```

the output for this one is. I'm hoping I can fix something in the condition, or maybe this is a completely wrong approach.

```
['bo', 'bob', 'bobo', 'boo', 'boob', 'boobook', 'book', 'bookwork', 'boor', 'bor', 'boro', 'borrow', 'bow', 'bowk', 'bowwow', 'brob', 'broo', 'brook', 'brow', 'ko', 'kob', 'koko', 'kor', 'or', 'orb', 'ow', 'owk', 'rob', 'rook', 'row', 'wo', 'wob', 'woo', 'work', 'workbook', 'wow', 'wro']
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think your question is too broad as it stands now since you're looking for alternate approaches. However, you might try a few things. First, check out something like [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) for creating possible rearrangements of your input string. Then compare those to your dictionary (instead of the other way around) to find which are "real words".HTH.

Answer (score 2):

First generate all the potential anagrams by calculating all the word permutations and iterating over all the possible anagram lengths. Then filter `potential_anagrams` according to your `words` file `f`.

```
import itertools

def compute_anagrams(word)
    n = len(word) + 1
    permutations = {''.join(p) for p in itertools.permutations(word)}
    potential_anagrams = {p[:i] for i in range(n) for p in permutations}
    return [anagram for anagram in potential_anagrams if anagram in f]
```

Deomonstration:

```
>>> f = ['book', 'bookwork', 'bow', 'row', 'work', 'workbook']
>>> word = 'workbook'
>>> compute_anagrams(words)
['work', 'bow', 'workbook', 'row', 'bookwork', 'book']
```

Comment: Might be worth checking sizes first, since if `math.factorial(len(word))` is orders of magnitude bigger than `len(f)`, then this algorithm sucks. `'workbook'` is fine, `'internationalization'` not so much.

Answer (score 1):

You additionally need to test that for each letter in the dictionary word, it does not appear more times in the dictionary word than it does in `"workbook"`. You could do this for example using the method `count()` of `str`.

Of course there are other approaches that in the end might be more efficient, but it's not necessary to start from scratch in order to fix what you have.